# Docusign Create Envelope ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE using templateId

Tags: django, api, postman, docusignapi

> The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line.

I am trying to create an envelope using the REST Api from docusign and got this error. This was working a few weeks ago and now, I suddenly got this error. Below is my json body for the request.

```
{
"status": "sent",
"emailSubject": "Company Contract: Signature Required",
"templateId": "310439de-819e-404b-90d6-a468bc0e4e12",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "sample1@gmail.com",
        "name": "Buyer Buy",
        "roleName": "BUYER_PROFILE"
    },
    {
        "email": "sample@gmail.com",
        "name": "First Floor",
        "roleName": "SELLER_PROFILE"
    }
]
}
```

I also tried this request via postman and I still have the same error. I hope anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: The best I can offer is a suggestion to check DocuSign's recent API changes. They're a big company, I'd expect them to have public release logs.

Comment: Please update your question with the complete error response from DocuSign, not just the error code. You can use [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see it.

Comment: @LarryK, I already updated the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not added any DS Tabs for all the signers in your DS template `"templateId": "310439de-819e-404b-90d6-a468bc0e4e12"`. A signer in an envelope always needs at least on DS Tab on the document. So update your template to add atleast one tab for every Signer role and it should fix your error.